# how to add line break sass compact output

Tags: css, sass

I need to add extra line break when generate sass compact output.

SASS CODE :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) { 
    #header{ 
      width:100%;
      height:250px;
    }
}
```

CSS OUT PUT :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) { #header{ width:100%; height:250px; }}
```

But i need to add line break sass compact in media query line.
just like below code

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) { //my line break
 #header{ width:100%; height:250px; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Weird behavior. You try to mix minified and not minified blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really Really need that you can have fun with regular expressions and `on_stylesheet_saved` compass hook.